# IE8: JavaScript is null or not an object error?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a database driven website (I didn't code it, just modifying few things) and I'm having a problem in Internet Explorer 8 (IE8).

It works fine in IE9, Chrome, Safari, Firefox but not in IE8 (and definitely not IE7).

The problem is when a user comes to a product search page, they'll click on "select a category" from the drop down and make a selection, based on their selection the products will be pulled from the database and populate the second pull down menu. After that the user will click on a region in the map and the results will be shown.

I'm getting an error that says prod.id null or not an object (screenshot is attached = https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxZ5l.png). I am not sure why this is generated. Prod.id is not null.

Here is some of the code from my .php page:  Please see this link http://pastebin.com/VFYcdEqK

Thank you!

Comment: The best way to debug IE javascript issues is to use the javascript debugger available for IE on F12.  When running your page with the debugger engaged, an exception like this will drop into the debugger, point you at the exact line of code causing the problem and you can inspect variable values and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: As I understand he did just that: the code in pastebin shows the erring line.

Comment: It is always better to show the generated code [view source] and not the php code. That way we can see the object you are looping through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all this:

```
echo "var prods = {\n";
foreach ($prods as $k => $pl) {
    echo "\"$k\": [";
    foreach ($pl as $p)
        echo "{\"id\":\"" . $p['id'] . "\", \"name\": \"" . $p['name'] . "\"},";
    echo "],";
}
echo "};";
```

Try this:

```
echo "var prods = ".json_encode($prods).";";
```

See if that fixes your problem. If it doesn't, could you provide a working test page rather and PHP source?

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you. I'm having a new issue with IE7 now. After category is selected, the product drop down disappears. I can click on it(I know where it is positioned) but can not see it. Any ideas on this? Thanks again for nailing this issue in IE8.

Comment: Update: If a category is selected, it hides the product but if I change the category again the product pull down shows up.

Comment: Another update: For some reason it was about resizing the select box. It was styled width:95% and changing that to an equivalent px worked.